# Withdraw airdropped OMG tokens from wallet

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, wallet, omise

I'm trying to withdraw OMG (Omise Go) tokens that were air-dropped to some Ethereum accounts of mine.

How to do this securely, cleanly, easily?

Comment: So is it a requirement to do this problematically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*---Confirmed answer below---*

This works with **any ERC20 token** - not just OMG. This is the simplest, cleanest, most first principled way to separate your ERC-20 tokens.

This answer is useful for those who prefer to use raw command line Ethereum (e.g. `geth`, `eth`, etc.)

Simply enter the commands below.

Remember the following:

**Be sure to replace `myETHaccount` and `myOMGaccount` string variables with your own addresses!**

**If you don't have a destination OMG account, create an OMG on an exchange**. I use https://bittrex.com

**bittrex.com requires a minimum deposit of 0.1 OMG**

`//Official OMG ABI definition:
var omg_abi=[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"mintingFinished","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"unpause","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"finishMinting","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_releaseTime","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mintTimelocked","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Mint","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"MintFinished","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"Pause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"Unpause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}];`

`//Official OMG contract address:
var omg_address='0xd26114cd6EE289AccF82350c8d8487fedB8A0C07';`

`//now let's create an instance of OMG contract:
var instance = web3.eth.contract(omg_abi).at(omg_address);`

`//set your ETH address
var myETHaccount=eth.accounts[3];`

`//check your available OMG balance:
web3.fromWei(instance.balanceOf(myETHaccount),"ether");`

`//check balance of all your addresses in ~/.ethereum:`
`eth.accounts.forEach(function(e,i){console.log("eth.accounts["+i+"]: " + "\tbalance:" + web3.fromWei(instance.balanceOf(eth.accounts[i]),"ether") + " OMG")})`

`//set OMG address
var myOMGaccount='0xc0c941740a550e05c50c060168c2fda1f9a6ad7b';`

`//transfer full amount:
instance.transfer(myOMGaccount,instance.balanceOf(myETHaccount),{from:myETHaccount,gas:180000});`

### **PROMPT: ENTER_YOUR_PASSWORD**

`//Congratulations. You're done!`

`//Don't forget to lock your account:
web3.personal.lockAccount(myETHaccount)`

`//copy and paste the tx receipt and check it on etherscan.io (for example)
//**Note 1**: OMG contract can take 5 mins before it sends it to bittrex.com
//**Note 2**: bittrex.com takes 36 confirmations before balance will appear`

Comment: Pragmatically? If you trust MEW or whatever GUI you're using to safely split your ERC20 token from your ETH account, then that's fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Use any ERC20 compatible wallet. Like MyEtherWallet.com, Parity.io, Exudos.io, MetaMask.io and many others.

However, I recommend:

https://www.myetherwallet.com/, if you do not want to install anything on your machine.

http://www.exodus.io/, that is good but will require you to install it on your PC.